# python- using delay between tkinter's listbox prints

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

All i want to do is to make a time delay between each print on the listbox that is included on the GUI . 
i havent managed to get a result so far. i tried to use time.sleep () ... and after method.

here is my code :

```
from Tkinter import *

def func() :
    i = int (e.get())
    for x in range (0,i):
        listbox.insert (END, i)
        i-=1

master = Tk()
master.title("hi") 

e=Entry (master )
e.pack()

listbox = Listbox(master)
listbox.pack()

b = Button(master, text="get", width=10, command=func)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: You should check out the `threading` module.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using a GUI, you should always use [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) instead of sleep. If you sleep, the GUI will stop updating, so you won't get refreshed displays and nothing will work like you want it to.

To get the desired result in your code, you have several options. One of them would be using `after` to call the function that inserts into the Listbox and pass a new argument to it for each iteration.

First, you'll have to modify the Button command to pass the initial argument to the function using a `lambda` expression:

```
b = Button(master, text="get", width=10, command=lambda: func(int(e.get())))
```

Next, structure your function like this:

```
def func(arg):
    listbox.insert(END, arg)      #insert the arg
    arg -= 1                      #decrement arg
    master.after(1000, func, arg) #call function again after x ms, with modified arg
```

Note: You'll also need to make the function `return` if `arg` is less than `0`, or it'll run forever ;)